# AWS Lambda does not support connecting to resources within Dedicated Tenancy VPCs

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, aws-lambda

We are creating Serverless ASP.NET Core 2.0 applications("https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/serverless-asp-net-core-2-0-applications/"). Actually our production environment running on "Dedicated Tenancy VPCs", and AWS Lambda does not support connecting to resources within Dedicated Tenancy VPCs("https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html"). So our question here can we have any alternate to create aws serverless application with .net core that will run on "Dedicated Tenancy VPCs"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions, how you can achieve this:

1. You can configure proxy service that will have an access to your environment in "dedicated tenancy VPCs" and proxy requests. (NGINX can be an option)
2. You can try to review AWS Elastic Beanstalk solution.
3. [VPC peering](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-dedicated-vpc/)

Comment: Hi @Leonid, Is VPC peering good option?("https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-dedicated-vpc/")

Comment: Yes, it could work. 3rd option (and the best one) for your case.